# Cordova and Android 6.0 automatic restore issue

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, backup, restore

I am currently developing application using Cordova + Ionic for Android. 
I use LocalStorage and PouchDB for data storing.

Recently I have discovered that Android 6.0+ has a feature to automatically restore apps once installed (even debug applications installed not from play store).

Every time I install app LocalStorage and PouchDB data gets restored which is not kind of behaviour I need.

I have read that developers have full control of that backup system, may tweak what gets backed up or if they want completely opt out of the system.

Question is how do I disable it in Cordova, is there some kind configuration switch, I did not find any.